# Content extending off the edge of the screen

Tags: css

I currently have a layout where I have 2 rows of 4 boxes on top of each other as the standard layout.
I want to change this layout on mobile devices (media-screen), so it is all in a single row (i.e. 8 boxes on the same line), extending off the right edge of the screen. Then the user can swipe horizontally (pushing the row of content off the left side of the screen) to browse through it?
Currently each box is a div (clicking each box reveals more content within the box) and I think re-aligning them is easy enough (display: inline-block), however I don't know how to get it to extend off the screen so when you scroll horizontally, it doesn't move the whole page - it just moves that content across your viewing area.

The effect I'm trying to achieve is a bit similar to how a group of photos are displayed on your news feed on the iOS Facebook app (iPad at least).

Any tips on making this possible would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try setting the width of the outer `div` that contains the inner 8 boxes to the screen width. I guess you might be able to scroll in the content of a `div` if the content is to big to be shown. Otherwise javascript might be needed.